oracle database does not connect with knex
Good afternoon.
I'm trying to connect an oracle database with knex.
However, I receive an NJS-500 message whenever I try to connect.
I created a nodejs service with knex.
I've tried different ways, thick/thin and I always make mistakes.
I've already checked firewall and security ports.
Does anyone have an idea if I'm missing something?
Is there any other alternative tool in place of knex?
However, in sqldeveloper, sqlplus, tnsping and dbeaver you can connect normally.
This is my code:
const knex = require('knex')({
client: 'oracledb',
connection: {
host: '10.211.2.110',
port: 1521,
user: 'USER_SUP',
password: 'ABCDabcd123**',
database: 'superdr_pdb1.paas.oracle.com',
},
});
knex.raw('SELECT 1 FROM DUAL')
.then(() => {
console.log('Conexão estabelecida com sucesso!');
})
.catch((err) => {
console.error('Falha ao estabelecer conexão:', err);
})
.finally(() => {
knex.destroy(); // Fecha a conexão após o teste
});

version:
"knex-oracledb-connection",
"version": "1.0.0",
"dependencies": {
"knex": "^3.1.0",
"oracledb": "^6.6.0"


Typically my knexfile.js looks like:
module.exports = {

  development: {
    client: 'oracledb',
    connection: {
      user          : "scott",
      password      : "tiger",
      connectString : "localhost:1521/orclpdb1"
    }
  },
  migrations: {
    directory: "./db/migrations"
  }

};

